# NetBeans generated code for UI

Tags: netbeans-6.9, netbeans-7

Why is it that when I generate a code for a simple JFrame in NetBeans it always give me a very long code for a simple GUI, it's kinda messy, is there any plug-in? or compiler that will generate UI code just for the components?  in their position??

Comment: Because generated GUI code is rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans UI editor uses by default a layout (`GroupLayout`) that is meant to be used by such automatic tools. The resulting code is generally verbose -- as is almost any automatically generated code! Anyway, you can't touch this code (from inside Netbeans, at least), so why would you care?

If you need simple code, learn the properties of each Swing layout and use them to hand-code your forms, or through the Netbeans editor. As an added bonus, you will have far better control on your forms appearance (the default layout can easily behave not as intended when your forms gets more complex).